# ReportLab - on the CategoryAxis is it possible to add labels corresponding to the ticks?

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I am trying to build a VerticalBarChart.

On the CategoryAxis I'll have the bars grouped based on their date. Since every category can be confined between two ticks the idea is to add under the leftmost tick of a category a label that indicates the start date of that category and under the rightmost tick a label indicating the end date of the category.

Is it possible to do that?

So far I only found methods to play with the category label but no way to do it with ticks, or even a way to add labels to ticks.